# how to make a react component state change on window resize?

Tags: reactjs

I have a sidebar with a canvas animation which is created based on the size of the window.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(this.sidebar.current)
    let w = styles.width
    let h = styles.height
    console.log("getComputedStyle:", styles.height, styles.width)
    this.setState({ "isOn": true, "height": h, "width": w })
}
```

My question is how could the state change according to window size change? I am trying to add a window.onresize function, but I don't know how to pass the component and states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant to calculate the navbar `width` and `height` when the screen resizes then the better option is to use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) instead of [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Following would also work

```
  onWindowResize = () => {
    const { current: navElement } = this.sidebar;
    if (navElement) {
      let rect = navElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.setState({
        height: rect.width,
        width: rect.height
      });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onWindowResize);
  }
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-kate-kqpem?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

So, something like this?

You can create a function to handle the resize, and then hook that function to the resize event, also grabbing the height and width from `window`.

Also, don't forget to clean up the event if the component will be unmounted.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(this.sidebar.current)
    let w = styles.width
    let h = styles.height
    console.log("getComputedStyle:", styles.height, styles.width)
    this.setState({ "isOn": true, "height": h, "width": w })
    
    let resizeHandler = () => {
      this.setState({ "isOn": this.state.isOn, "height": window.innerHeight, "width": window.innerWidth });
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeHandler);
}
```